# Why one function got from a macro works while another cannot be compiled?

Tags: clojure, macros

Here's snippet:

```
(defmacro produce-constantly-fn []
  (constantly :value))

(defmacro produce-fn []
  (fn [& args] :value))

(defn test-fn []
  ((produce-fn)))

;; during evaluation of form below it throws:
;; java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
;; No matching ctor found for class clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614
(defn test-constantly-fn []
  ((produce-constantly-fn)))
```

Why last function cannot be compiled? The snippet can be considered as some sort macros abuse, but anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you defined your macro body without quoting and you are curious why it results in such a weird error message. If you really meant to define a macro for calling `(constantly :value)` then you should use quoting and it will work:

```
(defmacro produce-constantly-fn []
  `(constantly :value))

(defn test-constantly-fn []
  ((produce-constantly-fn)))

=> #'user/test-constantly-fn

(test-constantly-fn)
=> :value
```

Now going back to your case without quoting. It looks really interesting and mysterious so I did some digging. These are my findings:

When you define a macro:

```
(defmacro produce-constantly-fn []
  (constantly :value))
```

it will just create a function named `produce-constantly-fn` and mark it as a macro (it's still a Clojure function).

When you look into the implementation of `constantly` you will find (docs and meta omitted):

```
(defn constantly [x]
  (fn [& args] x))
```

Under the hood it will compile to a closure object which will implement `IFn` and will have a single constructor parameter to close over `x` parameter. Something like this in Java code:

```
public class clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614 {
    private final Object x;
    public clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614(Object x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Object invoke(...) {
        return x;
    }
    // other invoke arities
}
```

Now when you have following sexp:

```
(defn test-constantly-fn []
  ((produce-constantly-fn)))
```

I noticed that Clojure reader evals `(produce-constantly-fn)` which should return just a function object (produced by calling `(constantly :value)`) but I found in debugger that it produces `clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614.` symbol instead (notice the `.` at the end of the symbol - it is a Java interop form for calling a constructor). It looks like a function object/value gets somehow converted to a symbol representing its constructor call. I could find that the function value gets converted into `Compiler$InvokeExpr` object containing references to the compiled class name which is probably somehow converted into the symbol.

The reader tries to resolve `clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614.` further.  It gets transformed by the reader into a call to `clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614` class constructor with no parameter.

As you have seen above the constructor of that class requires exactly one constructor thus the compilation fails (in `clojure.lang.Compiler.NewExpr` constructor body) with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614
```

I am not sure why the Clojure reader transforms the function value to a symbol with constructor call interop form and causing such behaviour thus I presented only the direct cause of the error message and not the root cause why your code doesn't work. I guess it might be a bug or it was a conscious design decision. From the macro authors it would be better to fail fast and learn that the return value of a macro is not a valid code data but on the other hand it might be very difficult or impossible to determine if the returned data is a valid code or not. It's worth checking on Clojure mailing list.

Comment: I really appreciate your investigation. Thank you! Also you were correct in your assumptions: I intentionally omitted backtick in macro definition.

Comment: You're welcome. It looked so interesting that it was worth checking what's going on.

Comment: BTW, what kind of debugger did you use to do the examination?

Comment: I used Cursive. I have started REPL debug session and added breakpoints in `LispReader` and `Compiler` classes.

Comment: Great effort, @PiotrekBzdyl - and a few illuminating observations. However,  I wouldn't consider it a Clojure bug. A macro call is supposed to return a sexp, not a function, so in this case we are hitting undefined behavior. Maybe a better error message is the best one could hope for, but I doubt it's worth the effort.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl - I suggest you add to your great answer the summary that states that this use of macro results in undefined behavior - a macro must return a sexp, otherwise the compilation will surely fail. That will round up your response with the direct answer to the question - "why last function cannot be compiled."

Comment: @YuriSteinschreiber I have extended my answer. I wouldn't decide if it is a bug or not as I don't  know what was the expected behaviour of reader and compiler in such cases (instead of for example failing fast with a meaningful error message). Maybe it was a conscious design decision or maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is going on is: macros resolve before functions.

So if you call `macroexpand-1` on the function you get:

```
(def test-constantly-fn (clojure.core/fn ([] ((produce-constantly-fn)))))
```

Thus `((produce-constantly-fn))` is called before function and gives listed error.